# WPF - A propriedade SelectedItem, do ComboBox, não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selecteditem

<sub>Obs.: Essa pergunta foi a tradução adaptada da pergunta original, então todos os Updates da pergunta original estão juntos nesse texto, desculpem por isso, mas o tempo é curto e não consigo parar para fazer um texto melhor, mas obrigado pela atenção de todos. [(Pergunta original)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577321/wpf-isnt-binding-combobox-selecteditem)</sub>

---

Eu já procurei em todo canto da internet, porém, não achei nada que ajudasse em meu caso.

Eu tenho vários ComboBoxes pelo projeto e eu estava procurando uma solução para o AutoComplete, porque o Toolkit não me agradou, eu achei e apliquei no projeto, juntamente com o estilo para todos os meus ComboBoxes.

Depois disso, o `SelectedItem` parou de funcionar, alguem consegue me ajudar ?

Meu ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

Meu estilo:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnEdit" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" Grid.Column="2" Focusable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" BorderThickness="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="5,0,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,3,23,3" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                    <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome Margin="4,6,4,6" CornerRadius="4">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Meu ToggleButton

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource LabPetsStandardColor}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
            <Path.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LabPetsStandardColor}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LabPetsPressedStandardColor}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Meu TextBox

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="#00FFFFFF" Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                    <ScrollViewer.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                        </Style>
                    </ScrollViewer.Style>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Bom, depois de muito tentar, eu achei uma solução, não é a mais bonita e perfeita, mas é uma solução...

Se eu colocar a propriedade `SelectedValue` e o `Owner.OwnerTypeId`, funciona perfeitamente, mas não é das melhores praticas, certo ?

Meu Combobox agora:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

Bom, essa é a solução momentanea, mas alguem conseguiria me explicar o porque que o `SelectedItem` não funciona como deveria ?

Obs.: Quando eu troco a seleção, o `SelectedItem` funciona perfeitamente, apenas não quando eu carrego a `view`.

Bom, funcionou como eu disse, porém ele está indo 4 vezes na minha `ViewModel`, então eu troquei as propriedades um pouco:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

Bom, por enquanto, o WPF consegue achar o `OwnerTypeId` e quando eu troco de item, ele bate apenas 2 vezes.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Ok, um outro fato estranho...
Um outro ComboBox, com as mesmas propriedades, menos `SelectedValue`, está funcionando perfeitamente... Não consigo entender o que acontece.

Desculpem-me, esqueci de postar minhas models.

Owner:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string FormatedPhone
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Phone == null)
                return string.Empty;

            switch (this.Phone.Length)
            {
                case 11:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                case 12:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                default:
                    return this.Phone;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string FormatedCellPhone
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.CellPhone == null)
                return string.Empty;

            switch (this.CellPhone.Length)
            {
                case 11:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                case 12:
                    return Regex.Replace(this.Phone, @"(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
                default:
                    return this.CellPhone;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual OwnerType OwnerType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public Owner()
    {
        this.OwnerType = new OwnerType();
        this.Animals = new List<Animal>();

        this.ErrorList = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

OwnerType:

```
public class OwnerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public OwnerType()
    {
        this.Owners = new List<Owner>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque isso não é uma solução perfeita, é uma solução paleativa, e pra mim, não é o suficiente... Gostaria de entender porque não funciona para esta situação/contexto o `SelectedItem` e para outros funciona.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, depois de muito tentar, eu achei uma **solução paleativa**.

Se eu colocar a propriedade `SelectedValue` e o `Owner.OwnerTypeId`, funciona perfeitamente, **mas é apenas uma solução paleativa**, pois não está funcionando como deveria funcionar.

Meu Combobox agora:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

Obs.: Quando eu troco a seleção, o `SelectedItem` funciona perfeitamente, apenas não quando eu carrego a `view`.

Bom, o `ComboBox` está indo 4 vezes na minha `ViewModel`, então eu troquei as propriedades um pouco:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbOwnerType" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OwnerTypes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Owner.OwnerType}" SelectedValue="{Binding Owner.OwnerTypeId, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5,0,10,0" />
```

Por enquanto, o WPF consegue achar o `OwnerTypeId` e quando eu troco de item, ele vai até minha `ViewModel` apenas 2 vezes.